# User account needs password to eject Kindle in Calibre

Tags: calibre, kindle

My 12.10 computer has several accounts on it.  My wife has a Kindle Keyboard 3G that she manages with Calibre.  The problem is that every time she tries to eject the device in Calibre if asks for my password.  Mine is the main administrative account which may be why it wants my password.

I'm not at the computer so am not positive whether I could eject from the file manager without a password, though I know that other USB flash drives don't require it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this occur if you mount the **Kindle 3 (3G)**, when **Calibre** is not running?

*There are multiple known issues with conflict between Nautilus/OS and Calibre over mount/unmount. Also, some efforts to address this (eg. calibre-mount-helper) introduced security flaws, and are **not** recommended.*

---

The likely best fix is to use the latest **Calibre** version, from: http://calibre-ebook.com/

Comment: I should mention I went the "adding the PPA" route though I understand that there are many recommendations to go straight to the calibre web page for the latest and greatest. In any case things seem to work fine.

Comment: The PPA method is certainly safer, and has a slower pace of change. That said, the download page gets 'fixes' that the PPA version may lack. *IMHO This process needs to be more mature, given the number of people committed to using Calibre.*